# Can eclipse be configured to automatically find sources for jars?

Tags: eclipse

Suppose I have `foo.jar` and `foo-src.jar` is there a way to place the `foo-src.jar` somewhere where eclipse will find it by default without having to ask for the location of the source that corresponds to the jar.

I know that I can use a user defined library to specify the source for a .jar but is there some other way that requires making no changes to eclipse configuration or a project configuration?

Comment: One way would be to use Maven to manage dependencies. Then Eclipse can even *download* the source jar on demand automatically.

Comment: Maven is not an option in this case for a very long list of really good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is to define the library globally with all its settings (like Javadoc and sources), and refer to it in the build path of the project. You can do this under *Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables* or *User Libraries*.

If you need an automatic facility for this, try using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) through the [m2e plug-in](http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/). It automatically downloads the Javadoc and sources of an artifact (library) on demand. Of course, this is depending on the submitter of the library, but works most of the time.

Comment: I am familiar with the Global User Library it is what I am using right now, but I am looking for a way that is pure convention and does not require any settings just put the files in a directory structure that eclipse automatically understands.

Comment: I believe there is no built-in facility for that, but I might be wrong. Using any Maven-based build tool however (like Gradle, Ivy for Ant, Sbt, etc.) could help you with that.